# Finding the name of the Git repository

Tags: git, clone

On a server that I'm working, I find that I have Git support. Tired by going with [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) to do each commit, I'll like to clone that repository to my machine and push back only when I've done my local work.

how can I find the name of that git repository? On that Linux server I'm a user which has access with FTP and SSH. My web application is public available on the address `http://linux_server_IP_address/~linux_user`.

Comment: "I'll like to clone that repository" - if you don't know what "that" repository is called, how is any one else supposed to know?

Comment: how can I find the name of the repository?

Comment: What repository? How, in practice, are you identifying the repository that you are talking about?

Comment: exactly this is the title of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to know the *path* to your repository, not the *name*.

Assuming that your repository is stored under `$HOME/myrepo`, you could clone it that way:

```
git clone http://linux_server_ip/~linux_user/myrepo
```

But cloning via HTTP, you cannot push back changes to the server, so better use the SSH protocol:

```
git clone ssh://linux_user@linux_server_ip/myrepo
```

See the `man` page of [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) for more information about the different protocols.

Note that you won't be able to push directly to `myrepo` since it's not a bare repository. To push to `master` on `myrepo`, `master` must not be checked out on `myrepo`. To achieve this, go to `myrepo`, create a temporary branch (`git checkout -b nocommit`), then `git push origin master:master` and then `git checkout master` again.

The topic of pushing into a non-bare repository has been discussed several times here:

- *[How to push to a non-bare Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764380/push-to-non-bare-repository)*
- *[Git: making pushes to non-bare repositories safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075584/git-making-pushes-to-non-bare-repositories-safe)*
- *[cannot push into git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221859/cannot-push-into-git-repository)*

Comment: If there's a properly set up HTTP server, then pushing is also possible with HTTP. But i doubt, there is. You should also mention, that for SSH the username is needed.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the repository is the folder name of the parent folder which contains the repository (since you do your work on that server, it's the folder, which contains the .git folder). But if there's a .git folder, it's not a bare repository, and then push to that repository is very bad practice. You should create a bare repository, and then clone that repository and push to it.

Comment: In my project folder, I have a .git folder. Can I push to that repository?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't, because you would overwrite local work, that you would have done in the working directory on the server.

Answer (score 0):

What people here fail to appreciate is that you are just typing

```
git <command>
```

and you never see a hostname.

You have to find your .git  directory (it may be in a directory further up in your path), cd there and then check the config file, the whole URL you need will be there.